# if RVs $X$ and $Y$ are indicators of independent events, does that imply their complements do too?

Tags: probability, random-variables

$ p(X \cap Y)=p(X)p(Y) \implies p(X^c \cap Y^c)=p(X^c)p(Y^c)?$

im having trouble deciding weither the above statement is true or not, my intuation is that its true, can any one prove or contradict it?

btw, this is not Homework so no homework tag needed.

Comment: You mention random variables $X$ and $Y$ in your title, but your body appears to be about events $A$ and $B$. Which is wrong?

Comment: yeah my bad fixed it

Comment: What is the complement of a random variable? It seems like you're talking about events, $X,Y$ and not random variables (for instance, you're intersecting $X$ and $Y$).

Comment: @Pedro sorry i wasnt clear, X and Y are indicators for events that are dependet means that X gets value 1 if the corresponding event accured and 0 else. the complement of X then is the RV that gets value 0 if the corresponding event accured and 1 else.

Comment: Well, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $1-X$ and $1-Y$ are independent as well.

Comment: can it be proven?

Comment: Please read the **title** of your question and edit it appropriately. Are you asking about **dependent** indicators or **independent** indicators? $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ holds for **independent** events or indicators.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yeah wrong again, fixed it thanks...

Comment: Hint: first try to prove that $P(A^c \cap B) = P(A^c)P(B)$. Starting from $P(B) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^c\cap B)$ might help.

Comment: **Further hint** since you say you got nowhere with the previous one.  Try substituting $P(A)P(B)$ for $P(A\cap B)$ and then transferring this quantity to the left side and taking $P(B)$ as a common factor of the difference of the two terms on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible questions we might try to answer. First, let's prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $1-X$ and $1-Y$ are independent.

Hint: Consider $$\mathbb{Pr}(1 - X \leq a, 1-Y \leq b) = \mathbb{Pr}(X \geq 1-a, Y \geq 1-b) = \mathbb{Pr}(X \geq 1-a)\mathbb{Pr}(Y \geq 1-b)  $$

Do you also want to prove that indicators are independent iff the events they refer to are as well?

EDIT: If $X = \mathbb{1}_A$ and $Y = \mathbb{1}_B$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $A$ and $B$ are.

Hint: If $A$ and $B$ are not independent then $Pr(A)Pr(B) \neq Pr (A \cap B)$ thus $Pr(X=1, Y=1) \neq Pr(X = 1)Pr(Y = 1)$. Conversely, you might simply consider $Pr(X \leq a, Y \leq b)$ where without loss of generality we might take $a$ and $b$ to be  $0$ or $1$.

Comment: yes, that would be nice, i tried using the hint of  Dilip Sarwate but didnt get anywhere yet